# checking if mainActivity is called from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

In my application I go from `MainActivity` to `TrackingActivity` and later back to `MainActivity`. In this last step I use some putExtra's. This is my code for going back to `MainActivity`:

```
public void goToHomeWithData(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("avgSpeed", avgSpeed);
        intent.putExtra("totalDistance", totalDistance);
        intent.putExtra("altitude", altitude);
        intent.putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

In the `onResume()` method in the `MainActivity` I'd like to retreive this data with something like:

```
String totalTime = getIntent().getExtras().getString("totalTime");
Double totalDistance = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("totalDistance");
Double avgSpeed = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("avgSpeed");
Double altitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("altitude");
```

but because `onResume()` is also called when starting the application, the app crashes on the `getIntent().getExtras().getString("totalTime");` part since there was no Intent that called the `MainActivity`.

What I'm looking for is a check around the `getIntent`s to see if the `MainActivity` is called from the `TrackingActivity` or not.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look into `startActivityForResult;`

**in activity 1**

```
protected void launchSecondActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);

        startActivityForResult(i, 0);

    }
```

in second activity instead of launching a new instance of your first activity use setResult

```
 public void goToHomeWithData(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("avgSpeed", avgSpeed);
        intent.putExtra("totalDistance", totalDistance);
        intent.putExtra("altitude", altitude);
        intent.putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();
    }
```

**then in your first Activity you can listen for the result like so:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {

            if (data.getExtras().containsKey("SOMETAG") {
                theExtraYouCareAbout = data.getStringExtra("SOMETAG");

            }
}
```

*note this is pseudo code but should put you on the right path*

Comment: Is this possible without calling the `finish()` in `goToHomeWithData`? I'd like to keep the activity open if that is possible.

Comment: you could get rid of finish() and say onBackPressed() instead (assuming you don't call finish() in onBackPressed().. now its important to understand that by sending your activity into the background with out finishing it, doesn't insure it won't get killed or loose its states by the OS during garbage collection.. make sure you bundle your savedInstance states

Comment: why do you need to keep it running?

Comment: because the whole application is just two activities: a webview on one and a google map on the second. This shouldn't be too hard to handle and it will keep my googleMap data, including polylines and others, saved. onBackPressed() means 'when the back button is pressed'? Can I call that in my code?

Comment: yes, its a public method just say 'onBackPressed();'  again, if you are going to keep those activities running, be sure you look into savedInstanceStates just incase the users' device needs to free up memory http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: let me know if that works.. and don't forget to upvote/accept answers that work.. (assuming mine does ;) )

Comment: Okay, I've implemented your code and it almost does the job. Did use the whole method with finish() for testing purposes. you said 'data.getExtra("TAG")', which errored for me (The method getExtra(String) is undefined for the type Intent). Figured out data.getExtras().getString("totalTime"); might work but this returns null as a value although it's set right in the other activity. It does run the code within the 'data != null' check, so data is not null, although totalTime and others are. Got any ideas for fixing that?

Comment: make sure you are using the appropriate keys:

Comment: if (data.getExtras().containsKey("totalTime")) {
    totalTime = data.getExtras().getString("totalTime");
   }
totalTime is the key right? Or am I just being retarded?

Comment: AHH sorry, i might have missed typed.. yes "totalTime" would be your key for setting and getting the extra.. for strings try data.getStringExtra(name) or for ints data.getIntExtra(name, defaultValue)

Comment: in which defaultValue is..? the String one looks logical, since you just retrieve the String that comes with the tag.. but what's the defaultValue for?

Comment: In the case that you are retrieving an extra that is an integer you have to supply a default value incase it's not there..  just put 0 for default.. if the extra turns out to be null or not a valid int it will become what you provide as the default

Comment: if you are in eclipse when you type "data." if you hit ctr + space you should see some code hinting that shows all the methods available to you  getIntExtra, getStringExtra etc..

Comment: Okay, that works perfectly! Implemented the onBackPressed() too, but that seems to kill the activity. Main problem fixed anyway so I'll accept your answer. any suggestion? Looking into the savedInstanceStates, or anything faster?(:

Comment: faster?  you should always use saved instant states if you are planning on letting an activity go into the background and expect it to retain it's information.. even if you don't kill the activity the OS may at anytime due to memory constraints.. savedInstance states allow you to restart the activity as if it was never destroyed

Comment: it looks daunting but i promise its super easy: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState